# CAUTION: request is not finished yet

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, next.js

I'm facing this problem while using this **getStaticProps** in **NEXT JS** but its just happening on **Google Chrome** and when i use **Firefox** its good and just fine..

[Image Of Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Umj.jpg)

```
export const getStaticProps = async (ctx) => {
  const filePath = buildFilePath();
  const fileData = extractFile(filePath);
  return {
    props: {
      allUsers: fileData,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: Just wait and let it finish. Delay may be due to throttling. Test it on production build. If this happens even after waiting for significant time then please mention it here. Also `getStaticProps` is called only during build. I am guessing you have first tried opening the page on Chrome then later tried it on Firefox.

Comment: i waited for this and after it finished, another request will be send soo again it has the same problem. but its not make any problem in production mode and it works just fine

Comment: That's actually expected. In dev mode the client regularly asks server if anything was updated. Hence there are many requests. And, many times the connection stream is just kept open for hot reloading, so it may show you that the request is yet pending. You need not worry about this stuff from production perspective.